# Node.js can't get css file

Tags: php, html, css, node.js

i want to get css file via Node.js localhost. **index.php** load correct, **style.css** can't be loaded.

my structure files

```
app.js views
     index.php
     css
        style.css
```

my app.js

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

fs.readFile('views/index.php', (err, html) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
        res.write(html);
        res.end();
    });

    server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
        console.log('Server started on port ' + port + (Date.now()));
        console.log('address ' + hostname);
    });
});
```

my index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Your server is giving the html file to the client on every response, that's why your style can't be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna use php, maybe you should consider something other than js for the server. There are packages like MAMP etc. the reason css is not loaded is you only have one way of reaching your server, and that renders your index file.